# Android Studio onClick and OnclickListener not working once changed to another Activity

Tags: android

I've added my acivity class in this link

[Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gkl7.png)I am fairly new to Android and am having difficulty trying to add a button on my second activity. I am able to place a button in my main activity and then I use it to navigate to my secondary activity (using setContentView(R.layout.)) and then I use the same 'onClick' method or even 'OnClickListener' method but the button on my second activity just wont work on another activity. Maybe i am missing something

[image: [1[]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg4i3.png)

Comment: please post your Activity class...

Comment: You can't use same button for two layouts.. Make another button in your second activity's xml layout file

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but actually i have made two separate activity class with two separate xml's, also the onClick attribute is different still i am getting the error on my secondary activity. I can navigate to my second activity but then the button becomes un-responsive even if i want a simple toast i can't do that

Answer (score 1):

just try to do this:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);
    findViewById(R.id.about_us).setOnClickListener(new 
         View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });

   }
}
```

and in second activity again find your button in second activity xml by id and write onClickListener for it

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement two separate methods for two different buttons. I would suggest do these things in the Java code instead of XML.

You can do some thing like this:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.something.something);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //perform your operation(s) here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you try to use one layout.xml for both activities.

You need to declare method `click1` in both activities, not only in first.

It means that your first activity has to have method `public void click1()` and the second activity has to duplicate method `public void click1()`

Answer (score 0):

I know **it's old** however,

@Meikiem idea is great. When you use `setContentView(View View)` you are just setting the activity's
content to another view (xml), and thus not really using the other .java file which has another
`onClick` method defined for the second button.
[Activity's setContentView(view)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int))

You need to create an Intent and pass it along the startActivity method.
[Intent Definition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))