# Button not working when activity is changed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to write a simple to-do list, consisting of one title screen (which is a main activity) with a button that switches to the actual list (which is an another activity). However, upon clicking the 'Add' button on that another activity, nothing happens - the onClick function is not even called. How am I supposed to make this work?

I have tried to rewrite the code according to this solution, but nothing has changed: [Android Studio onClick and OnclickListener not working once changed to another Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529265/android-studio-onclick-and-onclicklistener-not-working-once-changed-to-another-a)
Moreover, I tried to implement the code using the first approach mentioned here, to no avail:
https://medium.com/@CodyEngel/4-ways-to-implement-onclicklistener-on-android-9b956cbd2928

Here's the MainActivity class:

```
package com.example.kandydatpl;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openChecklist(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TaskListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

MainActivitty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="openChecklist"
        android:text="Open Checklist"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="407dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

as well as TaskListActivity class:

```
package com.example.kandydatpl;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TaskListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private EditText itemET;
    private Button btn;
    private ListView itemsList;
    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);

        itemET = findViewById(R.id.item_edit_text);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
        itemsList = findViewById(R.id.items_list);

        items = FileHelper.readData(this);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        itemsList.setAdapter(adapter);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.add_btn:
                String itemEntered = itemET.getText().toString();
                adapter.add(itemEntered);
                itemET.setText("");
                FileHelper.writeData(items, this);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        items.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        FileHelper.writeData(items, this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and the correspoding XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TaskListActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/item_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:hint="Enter Item" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickAdd"
            android:text="Add" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/items_list"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="667dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your `TaskListActivity` class looks okay (it implements `View.OnClickListener`, and sets the `onClickListener` correctly to the button, and finally handles the `onClick()` event correctly). That said, can you include your layout files (`XML`)? Have you tried debugging to see if the `onClick()` event fires at all?

Comment: @TomLarcher yes, I tried to debug the code, that's how I found out that this function is not invoked. I'll add XML files as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `android:onClick="onClickAdd` in your xml file, you need to add the `onClickAdd` method to your `TaskListActivity` as follows:

```
public void onClickAdd(View view) 
{
      switch (view.getId()) 
      {
           case R.id.add_btn:
             String itemEntered = itemET.getText().toString();
             adapter.add(itemEntered);
             itemET.setText("");
             FileHelper.writeData(items, this);
             Toast.makeText(this, "Item Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;
      }
}
```

When you are using the `onClick` attribute in your xml file, your `TaskListActivity` doesn't need to implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface and thus you don't need to add the `onClickListener` to your `Button`.

Comment: Would it work if I changed `android:onClick="onClickAdd"` to `android:onClick="onClick`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure since i rarely using the `onClick` attribute, but it should work. In my opionen you should either implement the `View.OnClickListener` or add the attribute to your xml file. Both makes no sense to me (except you have more views, where some are using the attribute and others using the `View.OnClickListener` interface)

Comment: I added the method you mentioned, it still does not work properly. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Please remove this line: `btn.setOnClickListener(this)`. Just use the attribute and see if it works - OR - remove the attribute and use `btn.setOnClickListener(this)` to handle the click event.

Comment: I decided to stick to the second option, removed  `onClick` attribute from the XML file and still no success. Here's my current code for TaskListActivity: https://pastebin.com/dgT3rHzv

Comment: Did you debug your code to see if the `onClick(View v)` method is called? There is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Yes, and the debugger does not reach this method. Here's the full code, just in case. https://pastebin.com/BdR9gkr2

Comment: Ok...then i don't know whats causing this problem. I would suggest you to create a new activity with just one button. Only to make sure this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the listener below the button:

```
btn = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And use **Invalidate Caches and Restart** option

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the kAliert

Use either one
A) Implement View.OnClickListener which you had done so far, but delete this line in xml

```
android:onClick="onClickAdd"
```

B) Do not implement View.OnClickListener, and use

```
public void onClickAdd(View view) 
{
  switch (view.getId()) 
  {
       case R.id.add_btn:
         String itemEntered = itemET.getText().toString();
         adapter.add(itemEntered);
         itemET.setText("");
         FileHelper.writeData(items, this);
         Toast.makeText(this, "Item Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
  }
}
```

while maintaining this line in xml

```
android:onClick="onClickAdd"
```

Let us know if it still not working.

Comment: None of these methods work. I decided to stick with the method A), I got rid of "onClick" attribute from the XML file, and the button still does not respond properly. This is my current state of TaskListActivity code: https://pastebin.com/dgT3rHzv

Comment: For code in pastebin   
1. Kindly include the xml in the pastebin.
2. From 'public void onClickAdd(View view)' to  'public void onClickAdd()'
3. From 'onClickAdd(v)' to 'onClickAdd()' under your 'public void onClick(View v)'

Comment: Read this [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-click-events-button-android/#targetText=Onclick%20in%20XML%20layout,response%20to%20a%20click%20event].

Comment: I followed the instructions in this link and your advice, but still, no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The button needs to be assigned an ID which can be done by going to the design file->click on the attributes-> attributes->on the search icon type "id"->give the button and id of your choice-> click Enter.

after you must have assigned it an id, the next step is to implement an onlick event on the button in the code section, the body of the onclick event function must contain the code to switch between the two activities. below is the code sample`

```
package com.example.kandydatpl;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //replace "buttonid" with the id you assigned to the button

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.buttonid);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaskListActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`